# Column count does not match; SQL statement (org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException) - At inserting to table with NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: java, exception, h2, spring-jdbc

I want to save `User` instance to ***H2*** DB.

And I have got following exception for saving new user to DB:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column count does not match; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO Users (user_id, user_name, user_birthday, user_email, user_role, user_tickets) 
VALUES (?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ) [21002-191]
```

Here is DAO snippet:

```
@Override
public Integer create(User entity) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO Users (user_id, user_name, user_birthday, user_email, user_role, user_tickets) " +
                                "VALUES (:id,     :name,     :birthday,     :email,     :role,     :tickets)";

    SqlParameterSource parameterSource =
            new MapSqlParameterSource("id", entity.getId())
            .addValue("name", entity.getName())
            .addValue("birthday", entity.getBirthday())
            .addValue("email", entity.getEmail())
            .addValue("role", entity.getRole())
            .addValue("tickets", entity.getBookedTickets());

    Logger.info("Create user: " + entity);
    return getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().update(sql, parameterSource); <== It fails here 
}
```

SQL script for creating DB looks as follows:

```
----------------------
-- Create Users table
----------------------
CREATE TABLE Users (
  user_id        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  user_name      VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  user_birthday  DATETIME NULL,
  user_email     VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  user_role      VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  user_tickets   VARCHAR(100) NULL,
);

-----------------------
-- Create Tickets table
-----------------------
CREATE TABLE Tickets (
  tick_id        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  event_id       VARCHAR(30),
  tick_price     DECIMAL(8,2),
  user_id        INTEGER,
);
```

Here is `User POJO`:

```
public class User {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Calendar birthday;
    private String email;
    private String role;
    private Set<Ticket> bookedTickets = new HashSet<>();
    // getters / setters
```

I suppose that it can't write to `Set<Ticket>`, but I don't know how to resolve this issue.

***UPDATE:***

For performing DB access, I am using - `Spring JDBC`.
Exactly `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>
<bean class="net.lelyak.edu.dao.NamedParameterJdbcDaoImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

public class NamedParameterJdbcDaoImpl extends NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @PostConstruct
    private void initialize() {
        setDataSource(dataSource);
    }
}
```

DAO implementation:

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl extends NamedParameterJdbcDaoImpl implements IGenericDao<User, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer create(User entity) {
        // todo move SQL queries to utility class
        String sql = "INSERT INTO Users (user_id, user_name, user_birthday, user_email, user_role, user_tickets) " +
                                    "VALUES (:id,     :name,     :birthday,     :email,     :role,     :tickets)";
    // see create() at above text
```

***Any suggestion?***

Comment: Use you any jpa? eg. hibernate?

Comment: @Victor1125 I am using `Spring JDBC` - `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`. I have updated quetion.

Comment: You have right. In database you have String and you try put there object. 
If you need add collection, you should create other table for eg. user_ticket, where will be ids with user and ticket, and other table ticket.

Comment: @Victor1125 I have added `Users` & `Tickets` tables declaration, which I have so far. How should I add this middle table? Can you help with it?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I have changed it it `INSERT INTO Users (user_id, user_name, user_birthday, user_email, user_role, user_tickets) VALUES (:a,:b,:c,:d,:e,:f )`, but result is the same - `bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO Users (user_id, user_name, user_birthday, user_email, user_role, user_tickets ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?, )]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column count does not match; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO Users (user_id, user_name, user_birthday, user_email, user_role, user_tickets ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?, ) [21002-191]`

Comment: give few hours. Now I have lessons. After shool will show you code.
For me is really hard solution using JDBC. Better and modern is use hibernate or other implementation JPA standard. Is really easy to learn and get you better code

Comment: @Victor1125 ok I will wait for your answer.

Comment: What is value of column `user_tickets` supposed to be? What is the purpose? To me, it seems erroneous to even have such a column in the database, given that table `Tickets` has a `user_id` column, so this question is not as much about an error in the code, but caused by an error in the database schema design.

Comment: @Andreas Value for `user_tickets` is Tickets which user have purchased. The question is how to save this Set relationship to DB. Schema design can not be changed it is required.

Comment: @nazar_art *"It is required"*? What is? Should the tickets be stored in the `Tickets` table, in the `user_tickets` column, or both? If in the `user_tickets` column, how should multiple tickets be serialized into a text value of max 100 characters?

Comment: @Andreas `user_tickets` should be stored in the `Tickets` table. And now my question is - `how to save Set of objects to DB?`. How should this DB configuration look like at SQL script?

Comment: @nazar_art You remove the `user_tickets` column from the `Users` table, then create another method `create(Ticket ticket)`, and you call it for each `Ticket` object in the `Set`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104116/discussion-between-nazar-art-and-andreas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was with redesign the logic a little bit. Moving main part saving logic to parent abstract class:

```
public abstract class BaseDAO<ENTITY extends BaseEntity> extends NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport implements IGenericDao<ENTITY> {

    private final String tableName;
    private final Class<ENTITY> entityClass;
    private final List<String> fields;
    private final String insertSQL;
    private final String updateSQL;

    public BaseDAO(Class<ENTITY> entityClass, String tableName, List<String> fields) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
        this.tableName = tableName;
        this.fields = fields;

        // init SQLs
        StringBuilder sbInsertSQL = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sbUpdateSQL = new StringBuilder();

        sbInsertSQL.append("INSERT INTO ").append(tableName).append(" (");
        sbUpdateSQL.append("UPDATE ").append(tableName).append(" SET ");

        for (int i = 0; i < fields.size(); i++) {
            if (i > 0) {
                sbInsertSQL.append(", ");
                sbUpdateSQL.append(", ");
            }
            sbInsertSQL.append(fields.get(i));
            sbUpdateSQL.append(fields.get(i)).append("=:").append(fields.get(i));
        }
        sbInsertSQL.append(") ").append("VALUES (");
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.size(); i++) {
            if (i > 0) {
                sbInsertSQL.append(",");
            }
            sbInsertSQL.append(":").append(fields.get(i));
        }

        sbInsertSQL.append(")\n");
        sbUpdateSQL.append(" WHERE id=:id\n");

        this.insertSQL = sbInsertSQL.toString();
        this.updateSQL = sbUpdateSQL.toString();
        Logger.debug("BaseDAO(), insertSQL: [" + insertSQL + "]");
        Logger.debug("BaseDAO(), updateSQL: [" + updateSQL + "]");
    }

    @Override
    public Long save(ENTITY entity) {
        long res;
        if (entity.getId() == null) {
            res = insert(entity);
        } else {
            update(entity);
            res = entity.getId();
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Child DAO will have a look like following:

```
public class UserDAO extends BaseDAO<User> {

    private static final String USER_TABLE_NAME = "t_user";
    private static final String userFields[] = {"name", "birthday", "email", "password", "role", "enabled"};

    public UserDAO() {
        super(User.class, USER_TABLE_NAME, Arrays.asList(userFields));
    }
```

Also, make user table with auto-incrementing id:

```
----------------------
-- create t_user table
----------------------
CREATE TABLE t_user (
      id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY CONSTRAINT pk_user PRIMARY KEY,
      name      VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
      birthday  DATE,
      email     VARCHAR(60),
      password  VARCHAR(100),
      role      VARCHAR(300),
      enabled   SMALLINT(6)
);
```

Also, the model should be updated with parent logic:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    protected Long id = null;
    protected String name;

public class User extends BaseEntity {
    private Date birthday;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String role;
    private boolean enabled;
```

Answer (score 1):

Column `user_tickets` is `VARCHAR(100)`, but the value you assign to `:tickets` is a `Set<Ticket>`, so how is that supposed to work?

Spring doesn't know what you are doing, but it assumes that you're building an `IN` clause when using a multi-valued argument, e.g. `x IN (:tickets)`, so it replaces the `:tickets` with the appropriate number of parameter markers. E.g. if your set had 3 values, it would become `x IN (?,?,?)`.

Your `Set` is empty, so no markers are generated. Technically, I think it should have thrown an exception, because that wouldn't be valid even for an `IN` clause, but it doesn't.

So, what do you expect the value of column `user_tickets` to be if your `Set<Ticket>` had values? The string version of the `Set`, e.g. `[Ticket1, Ticket2]`? If so, then call `toString()`.

```
.addValue("tickets", entity.getBookedTickets().toString());
```

Then cross your fingers and hope that won't exceed 100 characters.

Comment: @Victor1125 `SELECT * FROM Tickets WHERE user_id = :userId`? *(replace `*` with actual column names)*.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I have forgotten.
My assumptions are user can have many tickets and one tickets belong to only one user. You cant save on database cell all collection, so solution is change relation and save user id on ticket. Bellow is all. I created service class, wich check if you have user on database, if not - save it.

```
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
private String name;
private Calendar birthday;
private String email;
private String role;

@Transient
private Set<Ticket> bookedTickets = new HashSet<>(); //I cant save collection into database

//getters and setters
```

}

```
@Entity
public class Ticket {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
private String desc;
private int number;
/** id of customer as owner this ticket */
@ManyToOne
private User user;

//getters and setters
```

}

in userDAO method to save:

```
public void save(User user){
     String sql = "INSERT INTO User ( name, birthday, email, role) VALUES (:name, :birthday, :email, :role)";

     SqlParameterSource parameterSource =
                new MapSqlParameterSource("name", user.getName())
                .addValue("birthday", user.getBirthday())
                .addValue("email", user.getEmail())
                .addValue("role", user.getRole());

     namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(sql, parameterSource);

     sql="SELECT id FROM User WHERE name = :name AND birthday=:birthday AND email=:email AND role=:role";
     Integer id = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(sql, parameterSource, new ResultSetExtractor<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer extractData(ResultSet result) throws SQLException,DataAccessException {
            return result.getInt("id");
        }
    });
    user.setId(id); 
 }
```

in ticketDAO method for save:

```
     public void save(Ticket ticket){
     String sql = "INSERT INTO Ticket  (desc , number, user_id) VALUES (:desc, :number, :userId)";

     SqlParameterSource parameterSource =
                new MapSqlParameterSource("desc", ticket.getDesc())
                .addValue("number", ticket.getNumber())
                .addValue("userId", ticket.getUser().getId());

     namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(sql, parameterSource);
 }
```

and service for saveTickets:

```
public class UserService {
private TicketDAO ticketDAO;
private UserDAO userDAO;

public void saveTicketsForUser(User user){
    if(user.getId()==null){
        //if user is not saved in database
        userDAO.save(user);
    }else{
        //if you have this client in database, you don't need to save client
    }
    for(Ticket ticket: user.getBookedTickets()){
        ticket.setUser(user);
        ticketDAO.save(ticket);
    }
}
```

}

you can inject dao classes into service using xml.

Comment: Anyway, my sugestion is use hibernate instead clear jdbc.